# How can I animate these two things on one div?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

Here is a live version http://lucasdebelder.be/googledoodle/

First of all I kinda want to fix it without using javascript/jquery, I want to keep it pure HTML & CSS based :)

**Focus on the portals,** I want to make them open and shrink after my ufo passed them. I've tried it multiple things but it doesn't want to work. How can I make a transition without using a :hover statement? I have a glowing, which is the box-shadows already on it, to make it look interactive, but how can I make them shrink?

*(Portaal stands for portal, links stands for left and rechts stands for right, it's dutch)*

HTML:

```
<!-- portaal links en rechts -->
            <div class="portaal portaal_links_glow"></div>
            <div class="portaal portaal_rechts_glow"></div>
```

CSS:

```
/*portaal algemeen*/
.portaal {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50px / 100px;
    bottom: 315px;
}
/*portaal links*/
.portaal_links_glow {
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    opacity: 0.75;
    left: 50px;
    animation-name: animation_portaal_glow_links;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: 2;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
/*portaal rechts*/
.portaal_rechts_glow {
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(237,160,118,1) 0%,rgba(241,116,50,1) 50%,rgba(234,85,7,1) 51%,rgba(251,149,94,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    opacity: 0.65;
    left: 750px;
    animation-name: animation_portaal_glow_rechts;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
/*portaal glow animatie LINKS*/
@keyframes animation_portaal_glow_links {
    0% { box-shadow: 0 0 0px #57B6FF; }
    50% { box-shadow: 0 0 55px #57B6FF; }
    100% { box-shadow: 0 0 0px #57B6FF; }
}
/*portaal glow animatie rechts*/
@keyframes animation_portaal_glow_rechts {
    0% { box-shadow: 0 0 0px #ea2803; }
    50% { box-shadow: 0 0 55px #ea2803; }
    100% { box-shadow: 0 0 0px #ea2803; }
}
```

Thanks for all the effort and time.

Comment: Have you tried `transition-delay` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using css only

replace you keyframes `@keyframes animation_portaal_glow_links` and `animation_portaal_glow_rechts`  and the classes `.portaal_links_glow` and `.portaal_rechts_glow` with the following codes below

```
.portaal {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50px / 100px;
    bottom: 315px;
}
/*portaal links*/
.portaal_links_glow {
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    opacity: 0.75;
    left: 50px;
    animation-name: animation_portaal_glow_links;
    animation-delay: 5s;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

/*portaal rechts*/
.portaal_rechts_glow {
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(237,160,118,1) 0%,rgba(241,116,50,1) 50%,rgba(234,85,7,1) 51%,rgba(251,149,94,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    opacity: 0.65;
    left: 750px;
    animation-name: animation_portaal_glow_links;
    animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
/*portaal glow animatie LINKS*/
@keyframes animation_portaal_glow_links {
    0% { box-shadow: 0 0 0px #57B6FF; }
    50% { box-shadow: 0 0 55px #57B6FF; }
    100% { box-shadow: 0 0 0px #57B6FF; opacity:0;width:0;height:0}
}
/*portaal glow animatie rechts*/
@keyframes animation_portaal_glow_rechts {
    0% { box-shadow: 0 0 0px #ea2803; }
    50% { box-shadow: 0 0 55px #ea2803; }
    100% { box-shadow: 0 0 0px #ea2803; }
}
```

[pen is here](http://codepen.io/repzeroworld/pen/YZBerv)
Note in the pen I copied you entire css spreadsheets and place it in the css section

Comment: Thanks, this helped out my problem

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to shrink the portal :

```
transform: scale(0.2);
transition: 0.3s;
```

or maybe this :/

```
background-size: 100%;
/* background-size: 50%; */
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 50%;
transition: 0.3s;
```

i don't know how to get it full HTML + CSS :/
but you can use js to set a new style when it's needed

for example on your HTML page you can add this below :

```
<style>

/*the closing animation of the portal*/

.portal_style1 {
    /*your code ...* /
    animation: animation1;
}

.portal_style2 {
    /*your code ...* /
    animation: animation2;
}

</style>
```

the js :

```
function change_style(){
    var obj=document.getElementById("portal2");
    obj.className=".portal_style2";

}
```

and you can call the change_style() function when you want without the hover event

Comment: They want a css solution

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I kinda want to stay with only CSS & HTML